# Locust Error: HttpError (u'405 Client Error: Not Allowed for url: https://..../login')

Tags: python, load-testing, locust

I am trying to do load test of a web server and I disabled the ssl certificate for that site using `self.client.verify = False`.

```
from locust import HttpLocust, TaskSet, task

class UserBehavior(TaskSet):

    def on_start(self):
        self.client.verify = False

    @task(1)
    def options(self):
        self.client.options('//oauth/token')

    @task(2)
    def login(self):
        self.client.post("//oauth/token", {"username":"admin","password":"password","provider":"users","grant_type":"password","client_id":2,"client_secret":"somethinghere","scope":"*"})

class WebsiteUser(HttpLocust):
    task_set = UserBehavior
    min_wait = 5000
    max_wait = 9000
```

Now there is an error saying:
[image: locu]

Can anyone help me with this error? Thank you!

Comment: The operator of the server will be able to tell you why your client is disallowed. We can only guess.

Comment: why are you using // in the start of your paths?

Comment: @Cyberwiz. When I intercepted the request, the request was to path **//oauth/token** and was successful from browser.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to dump the dict to a string

Either explicitly:

```
self.client.post("//oauth/token", json.dumps({”username”...
```

Or implicitly, using the json parameter:

```
self.client.post("//oauth/token", json={”username”...
```

(edited, at first I thought the problem was the double slashes)

Comment: Thank you for your response. but if it was for the double-slashes. Why would the error occur for **/login**?

Comment: oh, i didnt see the request to /login (it is not in your code sample?). A double slash is technically incorrect (but might work anyway). Maybe the problem is that you are sending a dict as post body instead of a string? Try post(..., json={”username”...), or post(..., json.dumps({”username”...))

Comment: Hmm. Ok, the double slash is not entirely invalid, just very strange. One more thing: the number after the @task(x) is a weight, not an ordering. I think you’ll want to put both the OPTIONS request and the POST in the same task.

Comment: @pax did you have time to try these suggestions?

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion, json.dumps(data) worked for me.

Comment: Great! I updated my answer (rather than deleting it :)

Answer (score 0):

json.dumps(data) is the solution.

```
@task
def login(self):
    self.client.post("//oauth/token", data=json.dumps({"username":"admin","password":"password","provider":"users","grant_type":"password","client_id":2,"client_secret":"somethinghere","scope":"*"}))
```