# HTTPError('405 Client Error: Not Allowed for url: https://mywebsite/api/v1/authenticate'

Tags: python, load-testing, locust

I've referred to this question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59679869/locust-error-httperror-u405-client-error-not-allowed-for-url-https-l) but still doesn't solve the problem.

```
import time, csv, json
from locust import HttpUser, task, between, tag

class QuickstartUser(HttpUser):
    wait_time = between(1, 2.5)


    @tag('login')
    @task
    def Login(self):
        self.client.post('/api/v1/authenticate',data=json.dumps({"username":"user1","password":"Test1234","mode":"chrome"}),
        headers={'Accept':'text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/avif,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8,application/signed-exchange;v=b3;q=0.9',
        'sec-ch-ua':'"Google Chrome";v="89", "Chromium";v="89", ";Not A Brand";v="99"',
        'Upgrade-Insecure-Requestz':'1',
        'Sec-Fetch-Site':'none',
        'Sec-Fetch-Mode':'navigate',
        'Sec-Fetch-User':'?1',
        'Sec-Fetch-Dest':'document'})
```

I'm trying to replicate my Script from JMeter into locust.

[Error from Locust](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0q35I.png)

is it due to I'm trying to call an API?
I've tried using json.dumps and json as suggested and it still produce the same result. Any idea how to fix this?

Comment: If you own the API it might be a problem that the server is misconfigured

Answer (score 0):

HTTP status code [405](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Status/405) is *Method Not Allowed*. This might be caused for example by attempt of use `GET` on point which supports only `POST`. If you want to discover which method(s) given point support, you should do [OPTIONS](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Methods/OPTIONS) request and check value in `Allow` response's header.

Answer (score 0):

Is this a JSON REST api? If so it often requires an accept-header that mentions `text/json`.

Try adjusting the accept header, or remove it entirely and use `json={"username"...` instead of `data=json.dumps({"username"...` and the header will be added automatically.

If this doesnt help, then you should check the server logs for additional information.